# How to compare two dictionary and change the order of key if it matches

Tags: python, dictionary

main_list = ["projecttype", "emptype", "Designation"]

main_list is to check the key exist in the dictionary or not

Primary Dict

```
sample_P = {
    "query": {
        "emptype": ["Manager", "AM"],
        "Designation": ["Developer"],
        "from": ["0"],
        "q": [""], 
        "size": ["4"]
    }
}
```

Secondary Dict

```
sample_S = {
    "query": {
        "emptype": ["Manager"],
        "Designation": ["Developer"],
        "from": ["0"],
        "q": [""], 
        "size": ["4"]
    }
}
```

- Check the sample_P exist in the main_list
- Check the sample_S exist in the main_list
- Check if any key changes is there?
- If changes then changed key will goes to last part of the dictionary
- Only one key will change at one time

"emptype" key has changed in the secondary, if any change in the key it will goes to last

`{"Designation":["Developer"], "emptype":["Manager"] }`

Basically I need to check key's in the both dictionaries if any changes in the dictionary key then it will goes to last

Code is below

```
current_dict = {}
for key, items in sample_P["query"].items():
   if key in main_list:
       for key, items in sample_S["query"].items():
          #if values changes for the key #create a new dictionary and add to last part of dict
```

Comment: Dictionaries are sorted arbitrarily (though in more recent versions of python, they maintain insertion order). If you care about order, you should probably use a different type.

Comment: i m using python 3.8 order is preserved

Comment: Better to access the required keys using "get" to check if they exist instead of iterating over the dictionary

Comment: If you want order than use `OrderedDict` as it is designed to do so. On top of being much faster to do order-related operations, it has a `move_to_end()` method which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of key if that is smaller and access the value of key using get. I have stored the changes result to a new dictionary.

```
current_dict = {}
changed_dict = {}
for item in main_list:
    if sample_P.get("query").get(item) and sample_S.get("query").get(item):
        if sample_P.get("query").get(item) !=  sample_S.get("query").get(item):
            changed_dict[item] = sample_S.get("query").get(item)
        else:
            current_dict[item] = sample_S.get("query").get(item)
    else:
        print("key {} not found ".format(item))
current_dict.update(changed_dict)
```

Comment: This is wrong. `if sample_P.get('query').get(item)` is evaluated as False if `sample_P.get('query')` returns None, Use `if 'query' in sampe_P` instead.

Comment: @Maws can you check now?